# rnorm(1,mu,sigma), in R to MATLAB

Tags: r, matlab

I am using some code and trying to convert it from R to MATLAB.

I have found some code using `rnorm(20)`

I have seen that the equivalent functions in R and MATLAB are `rnorm(1,mu,sigma)` and `normrnd(mu,sigma)` respectively.

My question is: what is `rnorm(20)` actually doing and how could I replicate it in MATLAB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In R, `rnorm(20)` will generate 20 standard normal variates (`mean=0` and `sd=1` are the defaults). It is equivalent to doing `rnorm(20, 0, 1)`.

To replicate this in MATLAB, you could do `normrnd(mu, sigma, [20, 1])`. This gives you a 20x1 column vector of normally distributed variables having mean `mu` and standard deviation `sigma`.

Comment: Or, if you want to increase speed a little and not depend on toolboxes, `mu+sigma*randn(20,1)`